# What does Scrapy Job Setting mean?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub

I was reading https://doc.scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud.html#scrapycloud , and kind of confused what does it mean to override a Scrapy settings for a job. Does it mean that I can change the start_url? Or which setting that I can really override.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: the settings that are in the file settings.py inside your spider, you can find a list in the documentation page https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Comment: @MauricioCortazar can I add my own custom setting? like I want to add LIST_URLs as my start_url so I can overwrite it later using API.

Comment: I don't think so, it doesn't modify de file but you can try

Comment: check this https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider

Comment: and according with the message from the page it can be done `job_settings should be a valid JSON and will be merged with project and spider settings provided for given spider.`

Comment: ^ this should be the answer.  
To expand on this as far as I understand these settings will be only applied to current job, same as you'd use `-s` flags with your `scrapy crawl` commands for individual runs - here you'd use `job_settings` to provide multiple settings in json format.

Comment: @MauricioCortazar you can add last comment as the answer. I will accept it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreRumapea added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with the example provided in [the page you mention](https://doc.scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud.html#example), you can do it:

> job_settings should be a valid JSON and will be merged with project
>   and spider settings provided for given spider